# EF and Chinese Simplified in where clause

Tags: entity-framework, cjk

I have a simply query where I want to pull data out based on a QueryString value.  The query string gets passed in correctly to this EF statement:

```
_ctx.Products.Where(i => i.Category == CollectionName).ToList();
```

Looking at SQL Profiler the CollectionName above gets translated into ???

EX:

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[Products] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[Category] = @p__linq__0',N'@p__linq__0 varchar(8000)',@p__linq__0='???'
```

How do I get Entity Framework to parse this correctly?

Comment: Looks like the datatype of Category column is varchar. Try changing it to nvarchar and update the model.

Comment: That was the first thing I did and I was hoping that would work, but the linq still came back varchar, but instead of varchar(5000) it came back as varchar(8000)